# Command for setting Inline Length has no effect

Tags: db2, blob, db2-luw

I dropped a `CLOB(2G) NOT LOGGED` column in a table and recreated it with the same size and the `LOGGED` attribute.
If I look at the `syscat.columns` I see that the `INLINE_LENGTH` is 0. The old column had this value set to 312 which is the minimum value accepted.

However if I try to set the inline length of the column with the following command the value doesn't change

```
ALTER TABLE MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE ALTER MYCOLUMN SET INLINE LENGTH 312
```

The command complete successfully but apparently there is no change in the inline length.

The following query returns 1 record with a value of 0:

```
SELECT INLINE_LENGTH FROM syscat.columns WHERE TABNAME='MYTABLE' AND COLNAME='MYCOLUMN'
```

I would expect a record with a value of 312. Furthermore if I look at the DDL of the table there is no INLINE LENGTH specification.

I also tried to specify the inline length in the `ADD COLUMN` statement but the result is the same.

How can it be possible ?

Comment: How does it become apparent that there is no change in the inline length?

Comment: What DB2 version/platform? Could that be that you are looking at the catalog information for the table in a different schema? I'm asking because what you say sounds impossible.

Comment: I agree with @mustaccio. I tried LUW 11.1 and if I don't specify an inline length for a 2G clob a default value of 312 is used.

Comment: DB2 10.5 running on RHEL. There is only one schema in the database created manually. I know it's quite impossible and I have no idea of the reason for that. The only thing that come in minds is "row size limit".

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behavior is that DB2 must have enough space for the largest possible LOB locator in the column for the row in the table.

INLINE LENGTH is not like a VARCHAR where space is used only according to the amount of data.  It's like CHAR – the size you specify is reserved in every single row of the table.

From the [documentation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html) (scroll down to description of `INLINE LENGTH integer`):

> For a column of data type LOB, the default inline length is set to be the maximum size of the LOB descriptor if the clause is not specified. Any explicit INLINE LENGTH must be at least the maximum LOB descriptor size.

There's a table that shows the minimum explicit inline length for various LOB lengths, and for CLOB(2G), the maximum LOB Locator size is 312 bytes.

Therefore, for your table, the inline length must be at least 312 bytes to ensure that the largest possible LOB Locator can be stored.

Comment: So why omitting the INLINE LENGTH clause or setting it to an explicit value of 312 then the inline length of the table doesn't change ? Note that for all values > 312 it works.

Comment: You can't set INLINE LENGTH to something less than the maximum size of the LOB locator (i.e. 312 bytes for a 2Gb LOB) because it doesn't make sense.  In your table's definition DB2 will *always* reserve 312 bytes on the page for the LOB locator;  therefore any LOB less than 312 bytes can be stored inline.

Comment: So why the old column had both the inline length attribute in the generated DDL and a value of 312 in the syscat.columns and the new column doesn't ? My intention was to set this attribute to the same value of the old column. Do you mean that the column has an implicitly inline length value set to 312 ?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough if I specify a value greater than the minimum 312 ( even 313 ) the inline length is correctly updated in the syscat.columns.

Anyway the reason is still unknown.

I tried to do the following:

1. Drop the column as before
2. Recreate the column but with a value one point greater than before ( 313 )
3. List the value of the inline length
4. Try setting the default value for inline length (312)

The resulting inline length was always 0 in point 3 and after point 4.
However in point 4 i got an error which seems to be very clear:

***SQL20016N: The value of the inline length associated with type of column is too small***

This means that the value was correctly set to 313 but the value was not updated in the table syscat.column.

Furthermore after running a RUNSTATS on the table with the recreated column
I saw the following values:

- ADMIN_IS_INLINED( COLNAME ) = 1 ( which means that the column is inlined )
- PCTINLINED = 100 ( which means that 100% of the column is inlined )
- ADMIN_EST_INLINE_LENGTH( COLNAME ) > 0 ( e.g. for 'A comment' it was 13 = 9 + 4 for overhead )

Only after setting the inline length to 314 the value was update accordingly in the catalogue table.